# Multiply label with numbers with textfield with numbers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hope everyone can help me. I´m new in swift.
How can I multiply a label `l1` (get data(numbers) from pickerview) with an text field `txt` (get user input(numbers)). the calculate should be started with a button `b`. Thanks for help

```
class Flächenbewehrung : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var pickerDataSource = ["Ø 6","Ø 8"]

@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var l1: UILabel!

@IBAction func b(sender: AnyObject) {




}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    myPicker?.delegate = self
    myPicker?.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(row==0)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0,4"
    }
    else if(row==1)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0,6"
    }
}
```

Comment: How you want to multiply it? can you give any example?

Comment: user choose in pickerview for example Ø 6. Then the deposit value will show in mylabel (data from pickerview) = 0,4 ccm(see above). Then multibly textfield with user input = 5 or 6. Inputs are always numbers. Example multibly = 0,4 * 6. The results should be accumulate in a another textfield

Comment: Andreas, du wirst auf jeden Fall Probleme mit dem deutschen Dezimaltrenner bekommen (Andreas you will run into problems using the german decimal separator anyway). I'd recommend to use a number formatter to display the localized value but calculate with the native decimal separator `.`. To do math in Swift you have to convert the string representations to their numeric equivalents and you have to use the same types (`Int`, `Double` etc.) for the left and right sides of all mathematical operations.

Comment: @vadian - you speak german? Maybe i can explane it then better?

Comment: yes, but unfortunately the language of this forum is english

Comment: ok. for me it is not a problem to work with .separator. Maybe you can show me how i do the multibly and show the result. i read a lot of examples but i not can build the right for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you mean.

You could do the math operation in `pickerView:didSelectRow:`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  var multiplicator : Double = 1.0
  if (row == 0)
  {
    myLabel.text = "0,4"
    multiplicator = 0.4
  }
  else if (row == 1)
  {
    myLabel.text = "0,6"
    multiplicator = 0.6
  }

  let result = multiplicator *  (txt.text! as NSString).doubleValue
  // If you want to display the result in a label use
  // anyLabel.text = "\(result)"
}
```

the code does not contain any error handling for example is the text value in label `txt` convertible to `Double`

Comment: Thank you. no error is showing. but the label.text = "\(result)" only show the input in textfield.

Comment: Please see the comment lines. I commented out the line to show the result, because I didn't know what label is supposed to show it

Comment: Yes. I see. I do this. But it show only the textfield input..... I will test later again

Comment: ok i test it again. the problem is, if i write let result = multiplicator * 2 then he multibly it right. when i use let result = multiplicator * (txt.text! as NSString).doublevalue the label shows me 0.0

Comment: ok i find the mistake. how can i reload the ausgabe.txt when user fill the textfield? Now i must change pickerview, then he multibly.

Comment: What is ausgabe.txt? Please consider that we don't know as much as you know about your project. I just tried to describe how to do mathematical operations from `String` to numeric types and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry! ausgabe.txt is how in your example anyLabel.text = "\(result)". ausgabe.txt = "\(result)".When i run the project and choose pickerview row then in ausgabe.txt show only 0.0. After that i put a number in txt.text. Then still the ausgabe.txt show 0.0. Only when i choose the pickerview row again the ausgabe.txt will show the right value. I hope it is a little thing to do. So thanks again for your endurance with me :o)

Comment: That happens because the multiplication is performed only when the picker value has been changed. If you want to do the multiplication in the `IBAction` method `b`, you must declare the variable `multiplicator` as instance variable – outside any method – and move the multiplication line and the "display result" line into the method  `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply store the number separately from the labels, in different properties.  So for example you could do:

```
class Flächenbewehrung : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var pickerDataSource = ["Ø 6","Ø 8"]

@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!
var txtNumber: Double = 0.0 // Update this when you update txt
@IBOutlet var l1: UILabel!
var myLabelNumber: Double = 0.0 // Update this when you update l1
@IBAction func b(sender: AnyObject) {

  let result = txtNumber * myLabelNumber
  println(result) // Just for debug
  // store result somewhere or show it in your interface somehow

}
```

// ETC....

}

Comment: Thanks. But I will multibly mylabel * textfield. not multibly l1. l1 is for the result. i change that.Now i have a mistake (class Flächenbewhrung has no initialzier)??

Comment: I have updated answer with default values.  In Swift all non optionals must be initialised.  Either you give then a default value or you make them optional.  Try that: still an error?

Comment: That works. but not when i will show result in a label or another textfield. Sorry